# HQL Query with multiple criteria gives wrong results

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities, whith OneToMany relationship:

```
class Parent {
   int parentId;
   Set<Children> children;
}

class Child {
    int childId;
}
```

and the following HQL query:

```
"SELECT p.children FROM Parent p left join p.children as c WHERE p.id=:pid AND c.id:=cid"
```

is returning me all children of the parent with given id, while I would expect only a child with id matching given child id. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use inner join instead of left join.

Try either of the below, not sure of exact syntax.

```
SELECT p.children FROM Parent p inner join p.children as c WHERE p.id=:pid AND c.id:=cid
```

or

```
SELECT p.children FROM Parent p, p.children as c WHERE p.id=:pid AND c.id:=cid
```

Comment: That didn't change a thing... Had to filter results by hand as a workaround.